# Calling servlet function upon button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

My html page has

```
<div id="dialog" title="Items">
<div id="username">
<h4>Welcome <i><%=(String) session.getAttribute("username")%></i></h4>
</div>
<div id="disconnect">
<button>LogOut</button>
</div>
```

$("#disconnect").click(function(){

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "XXXservlet",
        success: function(data) {
             window.location.replace("index,html");}
```

}):

Now upon click on the log out button I want to call disconnect function in my servlet.Merely redirecting to a new page wont help.I want it the user to log out of application..How do I achieve with jquery??

Note:I am using doPost in servlet

Sorry if it is a simple question.I am begineer to programming

Thanks........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can take help of [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/getting-started.html) to accomplish this , on click execute servlet's method using javascript (ajax)
- You can use pure jQuery and make ajax call (GET) to some servlet which will do it for you

Comment: @jigar-Thanks...could do it by DWR...:)

Answer (score -1):

I would avoid using jQuery, DWR, or any client-server handshaking.

It looks like you're using ASP.NET.. 
You just want to log out right? Don't complicate things, just bind an event to your butotn in your code behind like so:

```
<ASP:LinkButton id="logout_button" runat="server" value="Logout"/>
```

In the code behind...

```
Protected Sub logout(Byval sender As Object, Byval e As System.EventArgs) Handles logout_button.Click
    Session.Abandon()
    Response.Redirect('homepage.aspx?ref=logout')
End Sub
```

Comment: @Atticus..I am using Java...Is there some thing similar in Java

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with JSP :(